# Error executing CURL request: Resource id #8

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to get more info what id #8 means? I get this error sometimes when trying to connect to endpoint. It seems to me like it is due to server not responding to my curl request but i am not sure. Thank you.

the error in error log is: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'abcApiException' with message 'abcClient::login | Error executing CURL request: Resource id #8 / [0]' in abc.api.php:51

line 51 is

```
throw new abcApiException(__METHOD__ . ' | ' . $response . ' / ' . $e->_header . '[' . $e->_status . ']', $e);
```

Comment: "#8" is an _id_ , not an error code. It references the resource number 8. The error you are looking for can be grabbed 1. in the error log your http server writes and 2. using the error handling methods the curl extension offers.

Comment: Please add your code so that a problem may be more obvious.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use curl_error($ch) and echo to diagnose the error

```
$ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
)                                                                       
);     

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$err_status = curl_error($ch);
echo $err_status;
curl_close($ch);
```